# How set the different colors for interfaces and usings for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I can't find settings for C# in vscode for set a different colors for interfaces/usings and [local variables/class properties] like in Visual Studio.

My current color scheme:

[image: My current color scheme]

This is like what I want:

[image: This is like what I want]

changed color settings:

[image: changed color settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, open the Color Theme picker with:
**File** > **Preferences** > **Theme** > **Color Theme**.

OR use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+K Ctrl+T` to display the picker. Use the cursor keys to preview the colors of the theme. Select the theme you want and press Enter.

To tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors, use `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` in your user settings `settings.json` file:

ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting

I borrowed that from ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes